# ZK, custom component. Different function (load and save) for one value

Tags: java, zk

ZK Framework. I have custom component v_dualListbox.zul:

```html
<hlayout hflex="1">
    <listbox id="candidateLb" hflex="1" vflex="true" multiple="true" rows="8">
        <template name="model">
            <listitem>
                <listcell label="${each.description}"/>
            </listitem>
        </template>
    </listbox>
    <vbox spacing="10px" width="24px">
        <image style="cursor:pointer" id="chooseAllBtn" src="/img/001_25.png"/>
        <image style="cursor:pointer" id="chooseBtn" src="/img/001_25.png"/>
        <image style="cursor:pointer" id="removeBtn" src="/img/001_27.png"/>
        <image style="cursor:pointer" id="removeAllBtn" src="/img/001_27.png"/>
    </vbox>
    <listbox id="chosenLb" hflex="1" vflex="true" multiple="true" rows="8">
        <template name="model">
            <listitem>
                <listcell label="${each.description}"/>
            </listitem>
        </template>
    </listbox> </hlayout>
```

I use it on zul page:

```html
<?component name="dual-listbox" extends="div" class="ru.it_constanta.pguAdmin.components.DualListbox"?>
<dual-listbox id="scopeDualLBox" chosenDataList="@bind(vm.orgScopeList)" model="@bind(vm.scopeList)"/>
```

DualListbox.java:

```
package ru.it_constanta.pguAdmin.components;

import ...
public class DualListbox<T> extends HtmlMacroComponent implements IdSpace {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 5183321186606483396L;

@Wire
private Listbox candidateLb;
@Wire
private Listbox chosenLb;

private ListModelList<T> candidateModel = new ListModelList<>();
private ListModelList<T> chosenDataModel = new ListModelList<>();

private boolean isLoad = false;

public DualListbox() {
    Executions.createComponents("v_dualListbox.zul", this, null);
    Selectors.wireComponents(this, this, false);
    Selectors.wireEventListeners(this, this);
    chosenLb.setModel(chosenDataModel = new ListModelList<T>());
    chosenDataModel.setMultiple(true);
}

@Listen("onClick = #chooseBtn")
public void chooseItem() {
    Events.postEvent(new ChooseEvent(this, chooseOne()));
}

@Listen("onClick = #removeBtn")
public void unchooseItem() {
    Events.postEvent(new ChooseEvent(this, unchooseOne()));
}

@Listen("onClick = #chooseAllBtn")
public void chooseAllItem() {
    Events.postEvent(new ChooseEvent(this, chooseAll()));
}

@Listen("onClick = #removeAllBtn")
public void unchooseAllItem() {
    Events.postEvent(new ChooseEvent(this, unchooseAll()));
}

/**
 * Set new candidate ListModelList.
 *
 * @param candidate is the data of candidate list model
 */
public void setModel(List<T> candidate) {
    candidateLb.setModel(this.candidateModel = new ListModelList<>(candidate));
    this.candidateModel.setMultiple(true);
    chosenDataModel.clear();
}

@ComponentAnnotation(
        "@ZKBIND(ACCESS=load, LOAD_EVENT=onLoad)")
public void setChosenDataList(List<T> chosen) {
    chosenDataModel.addAll(chosen);
    candidateModel.removeAll(chosen);
}

/**
 * @return current chosen data list
 */
@ComponentAnnotation(
        "@ZKBIND(ACCESS=save, SAVE_EVENT=onChoose)")
public List<T> getChosenDataList() {
    return new ArrayList<>(chosenDataModel);
}

private Set<T> chooseOne() {
    Set<T> set = candidateModel.getSelection();
    chosenDataModel.addAll(set);
    candidateModel.removeAll(set);
    return set;
}

private Set<T> unchooseOne() {
    Set<T> set = chosenDataModel.getSelection();
    candidateModel.addAll(set);
    chosenDataModel.removeAll(set);
    return set;
}

private Set<T> chooseAll() {
    chosenDataModel.addAll(candidateModel);
    candidateModel.clear();
    return chosenDataModel.getSelection();
}

private Set<T> unchooseAll() {
    candidateModel.addAll(chosenDataModel);
    chosenDataModel.clear();
    return candidateModel.getSelection();
}

// Customized Event
public class ChooseEvent extends Event {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7334906383953342976L;

    public ChooseEvent(Component target, Set<T> data) {
        super("onChoose", target, data);
    }
}
}
```

The data from database. On load page I want to put list of entity (orgScopeList) which already object has, I want to see them in chosenLb listbox. I use chosenDataList attribute for this. Also I want to save chosen object in same list (orgScopeList), i. e when client chooses more entity or unchooses it, I want to save it in orgScopeList, that why I use @bind annotation (for loading and for saving). So I need to listen two events onLoad and my onChoose for two commands (load and save). I wrote two methods with @ComponentAnnotation, but setChosenDataList doesn't work, nothing happens on load page and I don't know why.
I hope somebody understands me :) Help please!

Comment: Please look at [this example](https://www.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Component_Reference/Annotation/Data_Binding) which shows that save and load event can be defined together. Can you try first to join the 2 ComponentAnnotations into 1 on the getter: `ACCESS=both,SAVE_EVENT=onChoose,LOAD_EVENT=onLoad`? Furthermore, I think the `onLoad` might only be clientside, you could try `onCreate` instead. You can also try to just remove the load event definition. In this case the viewmodelwill initialize it once in the beginning and everytime you notify a change on it in the viewmodel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [Malte Hartwig](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7653073/malte-hartwig) for answer, both of his advices are working (to use `@ComponentAnnotations` only on getter and to use `onCreate` event as LOAD_EVENT), so that's what I have now in my DualListbox.java:

```
public void setChosenDataList(List<T> chosen) {
    chosenDataModel.clear();
    chosenDataModel.addAll(chosen);
    candidateModel.removeAll(chosen);
}

@ComponentAnnotation(
        "@ZKBIND(ACCESS=both, SAVE_EVENT=onChoose, LOAD_EVENT=onCreate)")
public List<T> getChosenDataList() {
    return new ArrayList<>(chosenDataModel);
}
```

But it is important to remember that LOAD_EVENT works after SAVE_EVENT too, so that's why `chosenDataModel.clear();` is written.